# how to display datetime in the same format in which it is given in sql server

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, my code is as follows:

```
declare @vCreatedDateTime datetime = '2013-05-27 13:57:43.023' 
select 'Date:' + convert(varchar(100),@vCreatedDateTime)
-- Output is May 27 2013  1:57PM  -- Format is completely changed

select 'Date:' + convert(varchar(100),@vCreatedDateTime,120)
-- Output is 2013-05-27 13:57:43  -- milliseconds are missing here
```

How to concat a input datetime variable exactly in the given format into any varchar variable.

I mean if (only valid date time formats)

input is '2013-05-27 13:57:43.023', output should be '2013-05-27 13:57:43.023'

input is '2013-05-27 13:57:43', output should be '2013-05-27 13:57:43'

input is '2013-05-27 13:57', output should be '2013-05-27 13:57'

input is '2013-05-27', output should be '2013-05-27'

This script block a part of a data script and the value for @vCreatedDateTime will be passed manually. Is this possible to convert ?

Comment: To do that, if you want milliseconds, must use `121` not `120`. Also, if you want to return different date formats depending in your input date format, you must compare them in some way to check if it is only date, date + time, date + time + millis... etc.

Comment: that was quick a reply.. I changed 120 to 121 and its working. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime will always be stored as `2013-05-27 13:57:43.023` so this is what you get.

If you pass in

- `2013-05-27` it becomes `2013-05-27 00:00:00.000`
- `2013-05-27 13:57` becomes `2013-05-27 13:57:00.000`

Like this

```
declare @vCreatedDateTime datetime = '2013-05-27 13:57:43.023';
select 'Date:' + convert(varchar(100),@vCreatedDateTime,121);
SET @vCreatedDateTime = '2013-05-27';
select 'Date:' + convert(varchar(100),@vCreatedDateTime,121);
SET @vCreatedDateTime = '2013-05-27 13:57';
select 'Date:' + convert(varchar(100),@vCreatedDateTime,121);
```

However, you can use [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) to only take part of the string. Note that you'll have to pass this in too.

And you need to use [format 121 to preserve milliseconds as per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)